# About multi dimensional numerical integration

Tags: computational-physics

I want to calculate 4 dimensional phase space integration.If anybody help me with a general 4 dimensional integration that will be OK. I can apply trapezoidal or *Simpson's rule* in lower dimensional case.

- But what about 4 dimensional case?

Comment: What about Monte Carlo?

Comment: I have no idea about that one. Can i do it in fortran? i know it is possible. But i need the way out

Comment: Did you consult a book about numerical methods? There is an awful lot of bad advice about numerical methods around. It's easy to do it wrong while believing that one's own algorithm is the best since the invention of sliced bread. Worse, still, whether a method is good depends on the data and we can't know your data.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has no physics context. If you put some work into researching the question, you might come up with a good question for [scicomp.SE].

Comment: The physical context is that we all need this type integration to calculate any scattering process, or cross section..As a beginner i need to learn this,